# Joomla Upgrade 2.5 to 3

Tags: joomla

I am trying to upgrade Joomla from 2.5 to 3 but update button is not showing on administrator panel. It is showing “Joomla! is up-to-date”. How will I get update button. Following errors came when I try to troubleshoot.

I am not able to get response from update.joomla.org. Is it due to proxy applied on my connection. If yes then could you please let me know the step to overcome this issue.

When I get in touch to our technical support team then they provide me proxy URL with port number. Without any credential. And they told me that I have to surpass this URL after using the proxy URL. But I am not sure how I can use this proxy to get response. Please suggest and let me know the solution. Thank you!!

Errors : 
**Update: :Collection: Could not open http:///update.joomla.org/core/sts/list_sts.xml** ;

**Update: :Collection: Could not open http:///update.joomla.org/core/jed/list.xml**

Comment: Errors : Update: :Collection: Could not open http:///update.joomla.org/core/sts/list_sts.xml ; Update: :Collection: Could not open http:///update.joomla.org/core/jed/list.xml

Answer (score 0):

Within the administrator area navigate to the 'Joomla! Updater' component (under Components) - when there click on the 'Options' button in the top right of the screen. When the pop-up appears, change the 'Update server' to 'Short Term Support' and click the 'Save & Close' button within the pop-up. Once closed, the updater component should go off and check for the latest version on the 'Short Term Support' branch. The text that said 'Joomla is up to date' should be replaced with the option to install the 3.5.1 version.

Make sure you take a backup before updating. Your template and other extensions may not be compatible with the 3.5.x branch so it's best to either make sure that they are compatible or find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

For others that might have been scouring the internet to solve this problem, I had the same thing happening to me on a very old site that needed to be upgraded.  I had an early 2.5 site which I managed to update to 2.5.28, but could not get any further due to these errors.

Most posts on this that you'll find will refer to the https version of the error, but in my case I had the same problem is the OP, where the file that could not be opened was on the http URL.

Trying to directly load the http site seemed to work, until I noticed that my browser was automatically redirecting to the https site.  I don't know if that was the browser, or a server redirect causing this, but it let me to another solution to this problem, which is that these resources obviously are no longer hosted on an insecure site.

Open up the administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate/models/default.php file and around lines 37-47, modify the listed URLs from http to https.  Then rerun the purge/udpate check cycle and you should now get the update found.

In addition to this, other sites that are listed as not being found on http links can be updated by modifying records in the #__update_sites table.  YMMV with these, as most of them are going to be 3rd party sites that may/may not have changed hosting.  In my case, most of them had just disappeared.  Notably, the core update site is listed in this table, but it gets overwritten by the aforementioned script, so updating the DB doesn't help.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user/developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and contribute to the dedicated Stack Exchange community.